# Is orthogonal complement in a Hilbert space unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let  $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $X \leq H$ where  $X$ is a closed subspace of $H$.  Suppose that there is another (closed?) subspace $Y$ with $X \oplus Y = H$ and $X \perp Y$. Is it true that $Y = X^\perp?$

**Attempt**:

Let $y \in Y$. Then $\langle y,x \rangle  = 0$ for all $x \in X$, so $y \in X^\perp$. Hence $Y \subseteq X^\perp$.

Conversely, assume $y \in X^\perp$. Then $\langle y,x \rangle =0$ for all $x \in X$. Write $y = x_1 + y_1$ with $x_1 \in X, y_1 \in Y$. We wish to show that $x_1 = 0$.  Then I'm stuck.

Is the statement even true?

Comment: Your proof doesn’t work, because it assumes that $X^\perp$ is unique.

Comment: $X^\perp$ is unique. It is defined to be the set $\{h \in H\mid \forall x \in X: \langle x,h\rangle = 0\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y \in X^{\perp}$. We can write $y=u+v$ with $u \in X$ and $v \in Y$. Note that $v \in X^{\perp}$.  Now $u=y-v \in X^{\perp}$. In particular $u \perp u$ so $u=0$. Hence $y=v \in Y$.